# Difference of index between an assigned variable and index on function

Tags: r, indexing

Consider this code example in R:

```
lab <- c("Prog->Makro", "Prog->Prog",  "Prog->Prog",  "Prog->Prog", "Makro->Makro", "Makro->Makro", "Makro->Makro", "Makro->Makro", "Makro->Makro", "Apop->Apop")

lab <- unlist(strsplit(lab, "->"))[seq(1, length(lab), 2)]
 [1] "Prog"  "Prog"  "Prog"  "Prog"  "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Apop"  "Prog"  "Makro"

lab <- unlist(strsplit(lab, "->"))
lab[seq(1, length(lab), 2)]
 [1] "Prog"  "Prog"  "Prog"  "Prog"  "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Apop"  "Prog"  "Makro"
[13] "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Makro" "Prog"  "Granu" "Apop"  "Makro" "Makro" "Makro"
```

If I assign my operation to a variable and ask for the index. I get the desired result.
If I instead call the index directly I get a different result. I seems like R cuts the array after the 12th index.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: In the part where you do two steps, you've changed the length of `lab` between the two commands. The two statements are not the same.

Comment: thats correct. if you would have answered I would have signed this as correct answer. but i cant with it beeing a comment.